# csv parser for header and detail lines in one csv file

Tags: php, csv

I have a requirement to import an order from a customer which will contain about 4 fields on the first row as their customer data i.e.

```
customer number, order date, order no, delivery date
```

The next X number of lines will contain two fields with the `product code` and `quantity` required.

I have other procedures that will pull in a standard price list etc and parse, but I am struggling to get my head around how to break apart the CSV file into the two different sections.

Any help or ideas on how this can be achieved will be appreciated

Comment: If it's just the first row, why not skip it? Its not really part of the CSV, its just metadata. And by skip it I mean read that line as separate process.

Comment: hi anthony, sorry i should have said, the first line will contain the actual header data, not column headings, the rest of the lines will contain line items. so no heading etc as very small amount of fields just two seperate types ;)

Comment: @Anthony's suggestion still holds, you can read the data on the first line separately and read the rest then use them together on your own internally.

Comment: Khaled if you can tell me how to read that first line on its own that would be great ;)

Comment: A possible solution would be using `fgets(...)` once on the file pointer (without setting the `length` parameter), it'll read till it hits a newline character. Process that line then send off the rest of the file to your other procedure to read the rest of the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will suggest using this library, its will give you column by `name` similar to sql result array

```
customer number, order date, order no, delivery date
```

Parse it in a way you want https://github.com/parsecsv/parsecsv-for-php

**example**

```
require_once 'parsecsv.lib.php';
$csv = new parseCSV('data.csv');
print_r($csv->data);
```

Comment: hi there i see the library has an offset and limit parameter. so i will be able to run two queries against the file right, 1 for the header line then offset for the detail lines?

Comment: I think it does see the [github repo](https://github.com/parsecsv/parsecsv-for-php) in Features : "Basic SQL-like conditions, offset and limit options for filtering data."

Answer (score 2):

Using the [parsecsv library](https://github.com/parsecsv/parsecsv-for-php) you could do this :

```
//get customer data first
// limit the number of returned rows.
$csv->limit = 1;
// Parse 'order.csv' using automatic delimiter detection.
$csv->auto('order.csv');
//retrieve the customer data
$customer_data = $csv->data;

//get order details after
//skip the first line
$csv->offset = 1;
// Parse 'order.csv' using automatic delimiter detection.
$csv->auto('order.csv');
$order_details = $csv->data;
```

Comment: oh man, i wish i had found this library earlier in my life, thank you so much for the help everyone. no idea who to thank for the right answer as all helped but i would say Saqueib for suggesting this library